# Email not sending or probably not being triggered on form submit Google Apps Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

Well we have this google form and the details are being added to google sheet with custom g apps scripts. When the details have been appended to the google sheet log, it should send email. If I run the sendmail() manually, it works but when I call it inside onFormSubmit(), it's not working. What could have gone wrong?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateLink = sheet.getSheetByName("Template Link").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  var logSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Log");
  var formResponsesSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var formResponsesHeader = formResponsesSheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, formResponsesSheet.getLastColumn() -1).getValues();
  
  var newFileName = e.namedValues['Name'][0] + "-" + e.namedValues['Date'][0];
  
  var populatedDocsFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1yTSd7W0U4Gcsm6CIw8NtD022F-MA7CPx");
  var templateDocID = DocumentApp.openByUrl(templateLink).getId();
  var newDocID = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocID).makeCopy(newFileName, populatedDocsFolder).getId();
  var newDocLink = DriveApp.getFileById(newDocID).getUrl();
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newDocID);
  var newDocBody = newDoc.getBody();
  for (i = 0; i < formResponsesHeader[0].length; i++) {
    var thisHeader = formResponsesHeader[0][i];
    var thisValue = e.namedValues[thisHeader][0];
    newDocBody.replaceText("<<" + thisHeader + ">>", thisValue);
  } 
  
  //Log
  var name = e.namedValues['Name'][0];
  var email = e.namedValues['Email'][0];
  var date = e.namedValues['Date'][0];
  logSheet.appendRow([name,email,date,newDocID]);
  
  //Trigger
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail").timeBased().after(15000).create();
  
  //sendEmail();
}

function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var logSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Log");
  var logSheetData = logSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var templateName = sheet.getSheetByName("Template Name").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  
  for (i = 1; i < logSheetData.length; i++) {
    if (logSheetData[i][4] == "") {
      //SEND EMAIL
      var name = logSheetData[i][0];
      var email = logSheetData[i][1];
      var date = logSheetData[i][2];
      var id = logSheetData[i][3];
      
      var pdfName = templateName + "-" + name + "-" + date;
      
      //PDF EMAIL 
      try{
        var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
        var blob = doc.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName + ".pdf");
        var subject = 'Document Created';
        //GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "This is just a test", {attachments: [blob]});
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {attachments: [blob], name: pdfName});
      }catch(err){
       continue;
      }
        
      //Log Sheet Update
      logSheet.getRange(i + 1, 5).setValue("Sent");
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("Custom Menu")
  .addItem("Build Form Submit Trigger", "formSubmitTrigger")
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem("Send Email", "sendEmail")
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem("Mismatch Check", "mismatchCheck")
  .addToUi(); 
}

function formSubmitTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onFormSubmit().create();
}

function mismatchCheck() {
  var result = "";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateLink = sheet.getSheetByName("Template Link").getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  
  var formResponsesSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var formResponsesHeader = formResponsesSheet.getRange(1, 2, 1, formResponsesSheet.getLastColumn() -1).getValues();
  
  var docBody = DocumentApp.openByUrl(templateLink).getBody().getText();
  var matches = docBody.match(/<</g); var noOfLessThanMatches = matches.length;
  var matches = docBody.match(/>>/g); var noOfMoreThanMatches = matches.length;
  var lessThan = docBody.search(/<</g);
  var moreThan = docBody.search(/>>/g);
  Logger.log([noOfLessThanMatches,noOfMoreThanMatches]); 
  
  result += "<b>Less Than Signs:</b> " + noOfLessThanMatches + "<br>";
  result += "<b>More Than Signs:</b> " + noOfMoreThanMatches + "<br>";
  result += "<br><b>Doc to Form Check</b><br>";
  
  var newDocBody = docBody;
  var reverseArray = [];
  
  for (i = 0; i < noOfLessThanMatches; i++) {
    var lessThan = newDocBody.search(/<</g);
    var moreThan = newDocBody.search(/>>/g);
    var subString = newDocBody.substring(lessThan + 2,moreThan);
    Logger.log(subString);
    var indexOf = formResponsesHeader[0].indexOf(subString);
    if (indexOf > -1) {
      result += subString + " - FOUND<br>";
    } else {
      result += subString + " - NOT FOUND<br>";
    }
    reverseArray.push(subString);
    newDocBody = newDocBody.replace("<<" + subString + ">>","XX")
  }
  
  result += "<br><b>Form to Doc Check</b><br>";
  for (z = 0; z < formResponsesHeader[0].length; z++) {
    var thisString = formResponsesHeader[0][z];
    var indexOf = reverseArray.indexOf(thisString);
    if (indexOf > -1) {
      result += thisString + " - FOUND<br>";
    } else {
      result += thisString + " - NOT FOUND<br>";
    }    
  }
  Logger.log(result);
  
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutput('<p>' +  result + '</p>')
  .setWidth(400)
  .setHeight(500);
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'RESULT');  
}
```

UPDATE: I have pasted the whole code instead above so you guys can see

Comment: Can you show the code where you are calling this function from the `onFormSubmit()` trigger?

Comment: hi yes, here ```function formSubmitTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onFormSubmit().create();
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register onFormSubmit as the function that handles the form submit trigger. Have you registered the function "onFormSubmit" like this:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit').forForm(form).onFormSubmit().create();
```

You might also want to check the registered triggers by clicking on Edit > Current project's trigger from your Apps Script project.

[Edit] Since the trigger is created properly, change the first the line of the trigger code from:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

to this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.source.getDestinationId());
```

Comment: Yes, I have that code ``` function formSubmitTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onFormSubmit").forSpreadsheet(sheet).onFormSubmit().create();
} ```

Comment: In that case, it is probably failing at the first line in onFormSubmit:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

You have to access the spreadsheet or form through the event (e.g: e.form), not through SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() which will work only for the script owner who has that spreadsheet opened.

Comment: Move sendEmail() to the first line. Or, get the sheet from the event:
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.form.getDestinationId());